# Angular2 : How to communicate from parent component to child?

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm loading some of div in between  tag. Its as bellow.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
<script>
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NewsfeedComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    SideMenuComponent
],
providers : [
    AuthGaurd
],
bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
] })
export class AppComponent {}
```

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    providers : [
        LoginService
    ]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
isLoggedin : boolean;
constructor (private loginService : LoginService) { }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginService.getLogged().subscribe((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        this.isLoggedin = isLoggedIn;
    }); }
}

home.component.html

<side-menu *ngIf='isLoggedin'></side-menu>
<top-bar *ngIf='isLoggedin'></top-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

auth.gaurd.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGaurd implements CanActivate{
    constructor(private router : Router) {
    }
    canActivate(){
        if (localStorage.getItem('isLogin')){
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        return false;
    }
}
```

**login.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    constructor(private router : Router) {
    }
    login(){
        this.setLogged(true);
        localStorage.setItem("isLogin","true");
        this.router.navigate(['/news-feed']);
    }
    logout(){
        this.setLogged(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("isLogin");
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    getLogged(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
    setLogged(val : boolean): void {
        this.subject.next(val);
    }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {
    constructor (private loginService : LoginService) {
    }

    login(){
        this.loginService.login()
    }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<input type="number” #mobileNumber />
<input type="password" #password />
<input type="button" (click)="login()">
```

**newsfeed.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'newsfeed',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'newsfeed.component.html',
})

export class NewsfeedComponent {

}
```

**newsfeed.component.html**

some html text....!!!!

app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path : 'login',
            component : LoginComponent
        },
        {
            path : 'news-feed',
            component : NewsfeedComponent,
            canActivate : [AuthGaurd]
        },
        {
            path : '',
            redirectTo : '/news-feed',
            pathMatch : 'full'
        }
        {
            path: '**',
            component: LoginComponent
        }
    ])
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Actually it's working fine when i'm going with clicks. like its launching perfect than on click of login button it forwards to newsfeed and shows the expected result. but when I'm going from the browser url, its not loading side bar and top bar component from the home.html

Comment: You need to use a shared service to communicate with components added by the router https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: I've tried with this. It's working fine for clicks but not working when i'm going through the browser url.

Comment: You need to provide more information. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish or what you tried or where the problem could lie.

Comment: No, please provide proper information then it's easy to provide a solution.

Comment: Yes I'm editing my question

Comment: Well its hard to explain please join me in chat so i can better understand you

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: What is the current behavior? What is the expected behavior? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No I'm not. Actually it's working fine when i'm going with clicks. like its launching perfect than on click of login button it langs to newsfeed and showing the expected result. but when i'm going from the browser url, its not loading side bar and top bar component from the home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fixes everything but I think you want to read the value from localstorage first to get the recently stored status and if you use `BehaviorSubject` listeners also get the last status if `this.subject.emit()` was called before a subscriber was subscribing.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    //private subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(false);
    private subject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(); // <<< changed
    constructor(private router : Router) {
      this.sublect.next(logalStorage.getItem('isLogin')); // <<< added
    }
    login(){
        this.setLogged(true);
        localStorage.setItem("isLogin","true");
        this.router.navigate(['/news-feed']);
    }
    logout(){
        this.setLogged(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("isLogin");
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    getLogged(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
    setLogged(val : boolean): void {
        this.subject.next(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its giving run time error because of following line

    private subject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(); // <<< changed


Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Then it should probably be `new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);`

Comment: Above one removes the runtime error but not giving the expected output.

Comment: Then I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered with that problem. Here is how I solve this situation;

- Create a shared service with observable fields as explained in official angular documents
- In your navigation bar component, subscribe to value from shared service to display navigation bar
- In login and logout pages, update value. Since you already subscribe the value, subscriber handle this situation by itself
- Create an authentication service. Add a method similar to this to ask your backend, is request authenticated;

```
//method parameters depend on what you want
isAuthorized(url: string, errorCallback: (any) => void) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(url)
        return this.http.post('account/isauthorized', body)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                //update value to display navigation bar if user is authenticated
                yourSharedService.observableField.next(true);
                return true;
            })
            .catch((response: Response) => {
                errorCallback(response.status);
                return Observable.of(false);
            });
    }
```

- Create an authentication guard and call `isAuthorized` method in `canActivate` or `canLoad` or `CanActivateChild`.
- In your callback, handle unauthorized requests. You can redirect user to error pages or remove the navigation bar, and whatever you want.

I hope it helps!

Comment: If you create a plunker with what you have already tried according to my answer, I can make changes and help better.