# A questions about angular2 route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is the official example of angular-router.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

[image]

[image]

If I have requirements like this:When user did not log in,He can not see the top bar(menu list in the second row of the picture should be hidden),only after he logged in,the top bar is visible,I thought a lot about this but can not find the solution.I dont know how to use canActive hook to control it,anyone has an idea please tell me,thank u.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h1 class="title">Angular Router</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  <a routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Admin</a>
  <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Let me be more clear about my question.When user loading page of structure like this.Where should I get and record the login status to achieve my goal,from route or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following code in your app.component.html

```
<navigation-bar></navigation-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Hypothetically, when user hit the url, user is redirected to another page directly. This is why I put `<router-outlet>`. For example, when user go to url, if user is not logged in, you can redirect it to login component. Afterwards, create an shared service as described in official angular documents.

```
//component-communicator.service.ts
export class ComponentCommunicatorService{
     private _showNavBar: Subject<booelan> = new Subject<boolean>;
     public showNavBar$ = this._showNavBar.asObservable();

     public showNavBar(value: boolean){
          this._showNavBar.next(value);
     }
}
```

You can provide this service from your app.module to other components.

```
//app.module.ts
...
@NgModule({
     ...
     providers: [
          ...
          ComponentCommunicatorService,
          ...
     ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

In navigation-bar.component.ts, you will have `showNavBar` field with the following code:

```
//navigation-bar.component.ts
export class NavigationBarComponent {
     public showNavBar: boolean = false;
     constructor(private componentCommunicatorService: ComponentCommunicatorService, ...){
          this.componentCommunicatorService.showNavBar$.subscribe((value: booelan) => {
               this.showNavBar = value;
          });
     }
}
```

Your job in here is subscribing to `showNavBar$` field. By providing that, whenever you update the value of `showNavBar$` in any place of your application, subscriber in `NavigationBarComponent` class handles this situation itself:

```
//navigation-bar.component.html
<nav *ngIf="showNavBar">
     ...
</nav>
```

For example in login.component, you can show navigation bar like that;

```
//login.component.ts
export class LoginComponent {
     constructor(private componentCommunicatorService: ComponentCommunicatorService, ...){
          ...
     }

     onLoginSubmit(/*params*/){
          yourService.login(/*params*/).subscribe((response) => {
               //do whatever you want
               this.componentCommunicatorService.showNavBar(true);
          });
     }
}
```

At the beginning of the application, since the value of `showNavBar` in `NavigationBarComponent` class is false, user will not be able to see navigation bar. By checking with your own control whether the user is logged in or not, you can update the `showNavBar$` field.

I hope it helps, please let me know if you come across any further question.

Comment: I have already answered a question like this one. You can also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523579/angular2-how-to-communicate-from-parent-component-to-child/40524307#40524307)

Comment: Yes,This is exacting what I want.Thank you very much!Splendid!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable(boolean) to keep the status of the user (user is logged in or not) . Then you can use it `*ngIf` to hide the bar.

for example

```
<div *ngIf = "loggedIn">
<-- this includes the bar you want to hidden-->
</div>
```

you can set the value `loggedIn` for in your `.ts` file while user logged in. initially keep it as false.

I think this would be helpful for you.. cheers ... enjoy coding :)

Comment: I dont know where and how to store the loggedIn value,can u tell me more.

Comment: please edit your question and provide the code how you logged in a user. are you use hard code user name and password or google auth?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use an auth service with an a`ccess token`. My favorite is `auth0`

This is what I do,

Set an auth token to local storage when user logs in. This is using auth0 but the same principle applies. You can create an auth token yourself if you don't want to use `auth0`

**auth.service.ts**

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http ) {
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.idToken);
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error: any, profile: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }

public authenticated(): boolean {
    try {
        var jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
        var token = this.accessToken;
        if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Now that there is a token in the `localstorage`

I do this in the `component.html`

```
 <span *ngIf="auth.authenticated() && auth.userProfile" class="profile-name">{{auth.userProfile.nickname}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="!auth.authenticated() && !auth.userProfile" class="profile-name">Account</span>
```

Comment: This is not my question,my question is if I want to have a login status to help me hide or show my top bar.But base on the structure from the document.how should I get from and store the status from the route.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. You can use localstorage where save login status in one variable once you logged in and based on that variable hide/show your header. And once you clicked on logout button change the status.

Please let me know if I understood wrong.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I dont know from where to get and store login status from the route.